# Moment.js procues multiple workers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, momentjs, web-worker

I'm playing with newest Webpack and Moment.js.
I've noticed that in my production build, moment.js is producing multiple (~30) files named `*random-hash*.worker.js` .

Is it something normal?

[Screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klzmr.png)

I did not set up any additional options and I'm really curious is this should look like that. Currently, I'm using another WebWorkers in this project and I would prefer to keep only mines. Maybe it's connected somehow with using `worker-loader` webpack plugin?

Answer (score 0):

A hash is added to a file so it is later easier to distribute your code to public.

Imagine you created your app and you want to make use of it as straightforward as possible, including download time for users with slow connection. In the same time you want to be able to update your application on the server and make sure all users always see *new* version of your app. A way to go is file caching in users' browsers but this causes lots of problems, nowever....

If you add hash to filename a webbrowser can cash it infinitely and if you update your code, you generate new file with new hash.

With this approach, when `index.js` gets downloaded you'll have different references there so webbrowser will download missing files, otherwise will use those from its cache

Comment: thanks for info! I know how hashes works, the question is - should it generate WebWorkers? Or is it webWorker at all?